# Looking for a good tutorial how to develop odata service in Java (with restlet, jersey, or odata4j)

Tags: java, odata, odata4j

I am looking for a tutorial that shows step by step how to develop an [odata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh237663) service using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odata4j docs about deploying a service in Tomcat look decent: http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/wiki/Tomcat

Also see answers to a similar question: [How do I interact with OData from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403359/how-do-i-interact-with-odata-from-java). That question covers odata clients in Java, but several of the links are relevant.

Comment: Thx for the link. I am looking for a tutorial. I asked this question, because I am quite surprised that there is no a step by step tutorial on the web for a ODATA service with Java. I need it as a material to introduce ODATA to my new collogues.

Comment: I believe that the first link is a (very brief) tutorial of the server side using odata4j's InMemoryProducer, and the second link is a tutorial of the client side.

Comment: Yes I know, I was looking for a tutorial for a while and I have investigated all the materials on odata4j and restlet. I see that these are the only ones.

Comment: The odata4j also makes samples available in svn. Checkout or browse from here http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/checkout.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get an idea of how to access and work with Odata from a client side you could try taking a look at this tutorial:

http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/archive/2011/09/13/accessing-odata-from-android-using-restlet.aspx.

It shows how to take an existing WCF service and auto generate the following class files for you to use within your applications. However, this example is specifically for Android and uses the Restlet library, but hopefully this can give you an idea as to how to access / use it.