# Using Delphi to consume oData service recommendations

Tags: web-services, delphi, odata, delphi-xe

I'm about to start a project that requires a Delphi XE Windows 32 client to consume an [oData](http://www.odata.org/) web service.

I can  query the service correctly with some rough and read test code but it's going to be a slog writing a framework to handle the oData protocol - all the filtering, parameters, etc and handling CRUD operations for all the services. Note that this is the Win32 version of Delphi so I don't have things like linq, etc at my disposal.

Are there any Delphi programmers out there that have experience with consuming oData with Delphi? And if so, any recommendations for frameworks, components, etc that would help here?

Comment: "the Win32 version of Delphi"? There have been more than a dozen releases of Delphi (13 specifically, IIRC), and only one that was specifically .NET (Delphi 8); the remainder are all Win32. It might help to be a little more specific by adding a version specific tag as well (eg., `delphi-2007`, `delphi-XE`). :)

Comment: Delphi XE. I can see Remobjects have some oData support, does anyone have any experience of the components?

Comment: RemObjects seems to provide [server-side support](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Adding_OData_support_to_a_Delphi_Data_Abstract_Server_%28Delphi%29) for Delphi, I would contact them and ask about client / consumer side support for Delphi

Comment: They have no client-side support. See: http://connect.remobjects.com/discussion/1428/odata-in-delphi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this by using a simple [httpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013820/117859) and then parsed the results with [SuperObject](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6)

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers are here:

[How do I interact with OData from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403359/how-do-i-interact-with-odata-from-java)

Available options I can see from the answers to that question:

1. Find a [Atom](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/atom/info) pub library for Delphi given that "Any library that can consume an Atom feed will be able to read an OData source. Any library that can perform the Atom pub protocol will be able to update an OData service." ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457986/80901))
2. Use an existing REST library as a foundation and add features like in the [Restlet OData extension](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/28-restlet/287-restlet.html)