# Parsing odata results from Dynamics using Delphi Tokyo 10.2

Tags: odata, delphi-10.2-tokyo, dynamics-365

Here's an example of some data from Dynamics CRM using the Web API:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://myurl.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/$metadata#bookableresources(_userid_value)","value":[
    {
      "@odata.etag":"W/\"40599496\"","_userid_value":"1648251b-9bff-e611-8107-c4346bc50748","bookableresourceid":"83bf299a-ac3b-e811-8161-e0071b670e51"
    },{
      "@odata.etag":"W/\"40599510\"","_userid_value":"cbd8b90f-9cff-e611-8109-c4346bc5c21c","bookableresourceid":"0a29b027-ad3b-e811-8161-e0071b670e51"
    },{
      "@odata.etag":"W/\"40599533\"","_userid_value":"9e311d06-75a1-e711-8136-e0071b6898c1","bookableresourceid":"fc3174eb-ad3b-e811-8161-e0071b670e51"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since Microsoft chose not to have D365 support the **$format** parameter, I'm left with having to parse this odata into something I can use, primarily a memory table. The RESTDemos sample supplied with 10.2 has an example of GETting JSON data to a *TClientDataSet* using the *TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter*, but that is incapable of handling the odata, or so it seems.

Yes, I could just write a bunch of code to split up the text into lines, then split the lines into name/value pairs, then format the values based on a sequence of nested ifs, but since odata is the new JSON, surely someone has already written a library to do this?

*Edit:*

Some strange behaviour I've witnessed, where executing the odata query from within **Chrome** gives me a XML formatted result:

```
<entry>
    <id>https://myurl.api.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/BookableResourceSet(guid'f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71')</id>
    <title type="text">Normatest Nurse</title>
    <updated>2018-05-17T05:19:22Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="BookableResource" href="BookableResourceSet(guid'f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/systemuser_bookableresource_UserId" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="systemuser_bookableresource_UserId" href="BookableResourceSet(guid'f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71')/systemuser_bookableresource_UserId">
      <m:inline>
        <entry>
          <id>https://myurl.api.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SystemUserSet(guid'1648251b-9bff-e611-8107-c4346bc50748')</id>
          <title type="text">Normatest Nurse</title>
          <updated>2018-05-17T05:19:22Z</updated>
          <author>
            <name />
          </author>
          <link rel="edit" title="SystemUser" href="SystemUserSet(guid'1648251b-9bff-e611-8107-c4346bc50748')" />
          <category term="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.SystemUser" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
          <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
              <d:FirstName>Normatest</d:FirstName>
              <d:TerritoryId m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference">
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid">c10a3010-0087-e711-8113-c4346bc540c4</d:Id>
                <d:LogicalName>territory</d:LogicalName>
                <d:Name>District Nursing All</d:Name>
                <d:RowVersion m:null="true" />
              </d:TerritoryId>
              <d:int_StaffNumber>T7777</d:int_StaffNumber>
              <d:int_ServiceAreaId m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference">
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid" m:null="true" />
                <d:LogicalName m:null="true" />
                <d:Name m:null="true" />
                <d:RowVersion m:null="true" />
              </d:int_ServiceAreaId>
              <d:int_Title m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.OptionSetValue">
                <d:Value m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true" />
              </d:int_Title>
              <d:LastName>Nurse</d:LastName>
            </m:properties>
          </content>
        </entry>
      </m:inline>
    </link>
    <category term="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.BookableResource" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:BookableResourceId m:type="Edm.Guid">f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71</d:BookableResourceId>
        <d:int_cmsobjectid m:null="true" />
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
```

But the same odata query from Delphi using *TRESTRequest* gives me unaltered odata:

```
{
"__metadata": {
"uri": "https://myurl.api.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/BookableResourceSet(guid'f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71')", "type": "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.BookableResource"
}, "BookableResourceId": "f2060c99-0653-e811-8162-e0071b659e71", "int_cmsobjectid": null, "systemuser_bookableresource_UserId": {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "https://myurl.api.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SystemUserSet(guid'1648251b-9bff-e611-8107-c4346bc50748')", "type": "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.SystemUser"
}, "FirstName": "Normatest", "TerritoryId": {
"__metadata": {
"type": "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference"
}, "Id": "c10a3010-0087-e711-8113-c4346bc540c4", "LogicalName": "territory", "Name": "District Nursing All", "RowVersion": null
}, "int_StaffNumber": "T7777", "int_ServiceAreaId": {
"__metadata": {
"type": "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference"
}, "Id": null, "LogicalName": null, "Name": null, "RowVersion": null
}, "int_Title": {
"__metadata": {
"type": "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.OptionSetValue"
}, "Value": null
}, "LastName": "Nurse"
}
}
```

I can only assume that **Dynamics 365** is parsing/encoding the response differently from a browser.

If I change the *RESTRequest.Accept* in Delphi to be the same as that reported for the browser,

```
RESTRequest.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';
```

Then I get a **'Response content is not valid JSON'** exception, but the *RESTRequest.Response.Content* is now the same XML format as using the browser.

At least now I can use the *IXMLDocument* interface and classes to parse the response into something a bit more manageable.

**Edit 2:**

Turns out that the CRM endpoint I was using was 2011, which does allow you to retrieve the results as XML. As identified by another of my questions, I have to be using the 2016 endpoint, and those results only come back as odata, so I'm back to finding a way to parse odata results in Delphi.

As far as I can tell, there is no odata equivalent to the *TJson.JsonToObject* parser in Delphi, so how am I supposed to go about it? Manually parse the text using *TStrings*?

Comment: I know nothing about Delphi but I googled 
 something called System.JSON.TJSONObject.Parse which sounds promising. WebAPI outputs valid JSON as far as both .NET and Javascript are concerned.

Comment: Hi Alex. Unfortunately, that is the problem I ran into. Using TJSONObject.Parse or TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue works fine with JSON text but Dynamics 365 can only return odata, so I'm left with either parsing the odata into JSON to use the System.JSON methods, or parsing the odata directly to an object structure using code.

Comment: Remy has a very good example as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815625/parsing-valid-json-with-tjsonobject-using-embarcadero-code-example-fails-with-ex that works well with JSON but fails with odata as the TJSONObject parser can't handle the odata format.