# java package equivalent to System.Data.Services.Client

Tags: java

Is there a java package equivalent to `System.Data.Services.Client`?  In C#, this is a suite of classes that provide what is known as WCF RIA.  It faciliates providing implementations of ODATA services in C#.  I would like to know if anything similar exists in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything in the java standard library, but there is [odata4j](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/)

More info at [How do I interact with OData from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2403359/850379)